# How to reset selected items from the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

In  component of office 365 fabric ReactJs exists [such component](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/detailslist). It has `_getSelectionDetails()` method which counts selected items from list 
 I want to make method which will reset it and will deselect items in list. For example we have button and when we press it, we reset all the items in the list, which we marked before. I tried to do :

```
_resetSelectedItems() :{
 this.setState ({ selectionDetails: 0 }) 
}
```

After I call it, it sets new state and sets 0, but items which were selected before remain selected, diselecting doesn't happen. How I can deselect items?

Comment: try using this._selection.XXXx , you have full documentation here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/utilities/selection/Selection.ts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this.setState()` performs a shallow merge of `this.state` into the new state, e.g. if `this.state` have `selectionDetails` and many more objects. `this.setState ({ selectionDetails: 0 })` will update only `selectionDetails` other will remain unchange. You have to cleanup other objects manually.

ref : [this.setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

**Update :**

finally i got it.... `this._selection.setAllSelected(false)` will work.

check out my [github](https://github.com/piyushdhamecha/office-ui-fabric-react-datalist-unselectall) project or check [online](https://codesandbox.io/s/G5oAOLjv5).

Comment: I understand it. I don't understand what objects must I clean else in order to reset selected items.

Comment: How you set selected items in UI, using state or props ?

Comment: I didn't writ any method to set selected items. It already exists. There is such method In constructor: this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => this.setState({ selectionDetails: this._getSelectionDetails() })
    });

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you very much. could you tell me where did you find out about this feature?

Comment: @SamFisher nowhere, just got all the methods by debugging..:)

Comment: browser debugger, or react developer tools?

Comment: Would love to know how to do this....the this._selection.setAllSelected(false) doesn't affect mine at all.

Comment: @NightTom this is the 4-year-old question. Please check your version. It's still working fine. Please check the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/G5oAOLjv5